# Adding url params to RestKit RKObjectManager putObject

Tags: objective-c, rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to send a PUT request with this format:

http://server.com/api/tag/:tagId?extra1=abc&extra2=def

```
 RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:@"http://server.com"];

 [manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Tag class] pathPattern:@"/api/tag/:tagId" method:RKRequestMethodPut]];

Tag *tag = [[Tag alloc] initWithName:name andId:tagId];
[manager putObject:tag path:nil parameters:@{@"extra1":@"abc", @"extra2":@"def"}
           success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
               [delegate onRequestSuccess:request withData:tag];
           }
           failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           }];

[delegate onRequestStart:request];
```

But the parameters get put into the body of the request instead of the URL as it does in a GET or DELETE request. The same happens for a POST request.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I've worked around this issue in the past:

Instead of making a route, just create your URL path manually, inputting your parameters directly into the string:

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"/api/tag/:tagId?extra1=%@&extra2=%@", @"abc", @"def"];
```

Then, call your `putObject` request using the `path` instead of the `parameters`:

```
[manager putObject:tag path:urlPath parameters:nil
           success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
               [delegate onRequestSuccess:request withData:tag];
           }
           failure:nil];
```

I'm not sure if this is the "correct" way to do it or not, but it should definitely work for you!